# Add style to sub menu item in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a bit complex scenario. I have pages and sub pages.I am trying to add 'style="float:left"' or 'style="float:right"' to each sub menu/page item depending on how the admin selects style for each sub page/menu item. So it's dynamic.

For eg,

```
A
  B (Can be float left or right)
  c (Can be float left or right)
```

I started in this way.

```
wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                      'menu' => 'Main Navigation',
                      'items_wrap' => '<ul class="clearfix">%3$s</ul>',
                      'depth' => 2,
                      'theme_location' => 'primary',
                      'walker' => new sp_Nav_Menu_walker()
                    )
                );
```

In my functions.php

```
class sp_Nav_Menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
}
```

I want to know which function should I write within the above class so that I can access all the menu/submenu items and overwrite them with my code.

Any help is highly appreciated.